# Play! Framework Java Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, playframework-2.0

i am relatively new to Play! Framework and trying to get a hang of it. I am trying to find if there is a proper, easy to grasp documentation out there.

I have few question like:

- Java annotation used in Play!

How would @NotNull (This one is from Javax) differs with @Required from (play.data.validation.Constraints).

What are other annotation (Play! specific) avaiable? and where can i get information about this?

Comment: Have you checked the play docs http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaHome and or the play JavaDocs http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/index.html ?